# Writing to a file named with variables in distributed JMeter testing

Tags: jmeter

Okay I've been having an issue with writing results to folders in JMeter.

I have set 2 variables, one for the name of the test and one for the submit date. I want the reports to be written to the folder named with these two variables.

Here's the variables:

```
TestRun = "Name of test"
DateRun = $__{time(dd-MMM-yyyy HH.mm.ss)}
```

The path of the folder to be written to looks like this:

```
C:\Tests\TestEnvironment\Results\\${TestRun}${DateRun}\file.csv
```

When I run it on the master machine, it's fine. It saves to the correct file and folder path, and ends up looking something like this:

```
C:\Tests\TestEnvironment\Results\Test Run 1 - 08-May-2014 08.55.47\file.csv
```

However, when I run it on remote machines, it saves it literally as below:

```
C:\Tests\TestEnvironment\Results\${TestRun}${DateRun}\file.csv
```

So I end up with a folder named "${TestRun}${DateRun}"

Am I missing something blindingly obvious, or is this an actual JMeter issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per JMeter help:

```
    -G, --globalproperty <argument>=<value>
            Define Global properties (sent to servers)
            e.g. -Gport=123
             or -Gglobal.properties
```

You need to use `-G` key so your variables could be distributed across remote clients.

so something like:

```
jmeter -r -n GTestRun=SomeName -GDateRun=SomeTime -t /path/to/your/plan
```

should help.

Alternatively you can create a .properties file and pass it to remote JMeter Engines via the same "-G" option.

I expect that if you want to use JMeter __time() function you'll need to wrap it with [__eval](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__eval), elsewise it will be treated as a string. Alternatively you can use operating system commands to retrieve current date and time.

See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](http://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for more information on dealing with JMeter Properties.

Comment: Hi Dmitri. Sorry about the late reply. Im using JMeter GUI, not command line. I should have specified that in my question.

The variables work fine for running it off a controller machine, but as soon as I run remote machine it changes it on the controller too.

Hopefully that makes it somewhat easier to answer.

Comment: Hi Cameron. You can pass the same `-G` property to JMeter startup script. If you omit `-n` it'll run in GUI mode but will still pick up the global property provided via `-G` argument

Comment: Hi Dmitri. Sorry I'm fairly new to JMeter. What startup script? Im just running JMeter.bat on Windows. The solution you suggested looks very unix-like.

Comment: Startup script in case of Windows will be `jmeter.bat`

Comment: I will give the above a try once my tests have finished. If it doesn't work I'll still mark this as best answer etc because it's not your fault I'm incompetent, and it seems like you have the answer :D

Comment: Okay I believe that worked! I edited the line COMMAND_LINE_ARGUMENTS and added -G, ran it remotely and it saved properly!

Was this the line you were talking about?

Thank you!

Comment: I've tried all these suggestions and nothing works for me. My controller is a windows machine and subs are linux